# How do I verify only year and month of LocalDate?

Tags: javafx, java-8

I want to verify only the year and month and print the message regardless of the day it is as long as the year and month are correct any ideas?

```
if (data.getValue().equals(LocalDate.of(2014, 1, 15)) {
    System.out.println("Success");
}
```

where `data` is a JavaFX `DatePicker`.
For example I want something like this

```
if (data.getValue().equals(LocalDate.of(2014, 1)) {
    System.out.println("Success");
}
```

But it doesn't work can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can anyone give me an idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (data.getValue().getYear() == 2014 && data.getValue().getMonth() == Month.JANUARY) {
    System.out.println("Success");
}
```

Comment: No problem, this is voluntarily self driven community Q&A site. Don't hesitate to ask any questions in a right scope regarding the site's rules. However, it is preferred if the asker shows his/her effort in a question. You could read the javadocs first, search the global net and search the stackoverflow for similar questions. As I said, you can ask any questions. If it is poor, badly formed or unrelated, it will be closed (even deleted) by the community members.